# Not working css style on a specific section

Tags: css, html

The css style

```
.sectiune_text {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

is not working on this specific section:

```
<div class:"sectiune_text">
<div class:"container">
         <h2>acesta este un titlu</h2>
         <p>exemple</p>
```

Comment: use class="yourclassname" not class:yourclass name

unless its some kind of pre-compiler

Comment: This is not correctly presented. You gave link but there is link. What is your actual problem.Mention your problem first.

Comment: thank you dude!You are the best,fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be

```
<div class="sectiune_text">
<div class="container">
     <h2>acesta este un titlu</h2>
     <p>exemple</p>
```

instead (`=` instead of `:`)